# java using printf for arrays

Tags: java, arrays, printf

I have a question on how to use printf on arrays. In my case, I displayed arrays by using `import java.util.Arrays;` and displayed them by `Arrays.toString()`. Or is it not possible with this method for displaying arrays, like do I need to use printf on arrays that are displayed by for loops? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is what I did in code:

```
public static void printResults(String[] name, double[] radius, double[] mass, double gravity[])
{
        // fill in code here
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(radius));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mass));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gravity));
}
```

and I called it in the main method like this:

```
printResults(names, radii, masses, gravities);
```

below is the output of my program when I execute it:

```
run:
[Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune, Pluto]
[2439.7, 6051.9, 6378.0, 3402.5, 71492.0, 60270.0, 25562.0, 24774.0, 1195.0]
[3.3022E23, 4.8685E24, 5.973600000000001E24, 6.4185E23, 1.8986000000000002E27,     5.6845999999999996E26, 8.681E25, 1.0243E26, 1.312E22]
[3.700465457603474, 8.8661999605471, 9.794740681676519, 3.697967684866716,  24.776754466506414, 10.43814587026926, 8.861473215210253, 11.131680688084042,  0.6128071987535232]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

I want to display it so that the number align with the names of the planets and limit the decimal place values to only 2 place values after the decimal (3.14)

Comment: You are right, you need another method, like a loop and `System.out.format()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be helpful for your needs.

```
public static void printResults(String[] name, double[] radius, double[] mass, double gravity[]){

    DecimalFormat decimalFormat=new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

      if(name!=null && radius!=null 
              && mass!=null && gravity!=null){

          if(name.length==radius.length 
                  && radius.length==mass.length 
                  && mass.length==gravity.length){

            for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++){

                System.out.println("Name="+name[i]);
                System.out.println("Radius="+decimalFormat.format(radius[i]));
                System.out.println("Mass="+decimalFormat.format(mass[i]));
                System.out.println("Gravity="+decimalFormat.format(gravity[i]));
                System.out.println();
            }


          }


      }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Name=Mercury
Radius=10.56
Mass=5.12
Gravity=1054.12

Name=Venus
Radius=10.67
Mass=10.45
Gravity=10.24
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

```
for (int index = 0; index < blam.length; ++index)
{
    String formattedOutput = String.format("format string", objects...);
    System.out.println(formattedOutput);
}
```

Reading assignment: [String API Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Option 2

```
for (int index = 0; index < blam.length; ++index)
{
    System.out.printf("format string", objects...);
}
```

Reading assignment: [PrintWriter API Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to loop through the arrays unto length of array and use [System.out.format method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) as @Keppil told.